# How many meaningful English phrases can be created using 4 or fewer words?

Tags: syntax, english, computational-linguistics

Prompted by [this exchange on Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32691/why-not-allow-spaces-in-a-password#comment196835_32692), regarding whether a passphrase consisting of 4 English words might be easier or harder to crack than a password of 8 random characters, including symbols:

> "Meaningful sentences have a lot of structure which drastically reduces the actual entropy."

**How many possible combinations of 4 or fewer English words will produce a sensible, meaningful, and complete phrase?**

Suppose I have a computer program with a dictionary of the 250,000 most common English words, and it will produce a list of all possible combinations of 4 or fewer words (250,000<sup>4</sup> + 250,000<sup>3</sup> + 250,000<sup>2</sup> + 250,000 total combinations), to be used for a brute-force attack. For this example, we'll ignore capitalization and likewise assume that punctuation can be added in order to allow the phrase to qualify - so the phrase `house is on` might not qualify, because it implies another word needed after `on`, but `"House" is on` turns `house` into the title of a TV show, making it a complete thought. But `a and and the` cannot be turned into a meaningful phrase through any change of capitalization and punctuation, nor can `correct horse battery staple` become sensible - while changing it to `Correct! Horse: "Battery staple."` might arguably make it meaningful (someone is accurate in their assertion that a horse uttered "battery staple"), it's still nonsensical (horses can't talk, and if they could, they'd still have no reason to say "battery staple").

So how many of these 3.9 sextillion combinations qualify as "meaningful phrases" and are therefore worth putting into our brute force attack on the "4-word max passphrase" website so that we can crack all the passphrases that were chosen by humans? We don't want to spend the much longer amount of time necessary to crack the passphrases of the users that used a "random 4-word passphrase generator", because we know that most people are too lazy.

While my above examples used sentences, this isn't necessary - `my car`, `the quick brown fox`, `piece of cake`, and `in the past` would all qualify as well.

I don't expect an exact number, as there's sure to be some degree of subjectivity with some particular combinations. But I'm thinking that there must be a way to tackle this question by starting with the possible valid arrangements of parts of speech, e.g. `noun preposition noun` is going to tend to be valid, while `adjective verb adjective verb` pretty clearly won't, and then by knowing how many English words can be used as adjectives, we should be able to arrive at a reasonable estimate.

Also - while I gave as an example a 250,000 word dictionary, feel free to use a different dictionary size, for example based on your choice of reference material, but if you do so, please indicate your dictionary size for comparative purposes.

Comment: I assume by "sensible" you mean "grammatical", so "the invisible cat" is in but \*"cat invisible the" is out. And "meaningful" would mean "can be assigned some interpretation", not "is likely to describe a possible situation" (cats only *seem* to be invisible). Where do you want "colorless green ideas" to be slotted in the count? Just looking at randomly generated N V combinations, you'll find a lot of cases of "Dogs teach", "Knives walk" combinations which don't describe anything in the real world; I assume you want these included, but best I not assume if I can ask.

Comment: I guess the best litmus test would be "Is it plausible that any human would think up this sequence of words, and remember them as a single idea rather than a sequence of four individual pieces of information?" So *dogs teach* and *knives walk* would both definitely count, but *colorless green ideas* would probably not, unless you can bring yourself to accept an idea being both colorless and green simultaneously.

Comment: "*A* and *And The*" seems quite a sensible free jazz band name to me...